# Rsync hangs forevers when I try to run it in cygwin

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am trying to run rsync command to copy diff of files. I am using cygwin as I am on windows OS, Rsync goes in hang state when I try to run it, this is what the screen looks like

```
$ rsync -avh data/pharma.mp4 rohit@192.168.100.6:
rohit@192.168.100.6's password: abc123
```

I am able to run ssh from cygwin. Also, A thing to notice is that, the password shows in the screen, unlike in ssh, when the password in hidden.

Also when I do ctrl+c to exit from rsync, I get the following output

```
$ abc123
-bash: abc123: command not found
```

Comment: Something's up with the entering of the password. It should _never_ show up on the screen as you type it. This probably means that it's never even getting to `rsync`. I don't unfortunately have access to a system with Cygwin...

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't run `rsync` (or any Cygwin commands, for that matter) from `CMD` or `Powershell`. Run it from the Cygwin terminal
2. Ensure you have Cygwin's `ssh` installed and in the `PATH` ahead of any Windows directories. Otherwise you'll end up using Cygwin's `rsync` with Microsoft's `ssh`, and that's not a happy combination. (Check which version of `ssh` with `type ssh` and looking to see which directory it's in)